# table-datatable dont work in chrome but they work in mozilla coreectly

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, datatable

Hi evry one this is the error : 
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/admin/Desktop/theme-7016215-scale-web-application-admin-template/src/js/datatables/datatable.json?_=1431362727587. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

and this is my file :

```
{ "aaData": [{
    "id": "1000",
    "browser": "567",
    "platform": "789",
    "version": "audi",
    "grade": "X"
        },{
            "id": "3",
    "browser": "567",
    "platform": "789",
    "version": "volvo",
    "grade": "X"
        }] }
```

Thank's :)

Comment: Most likely because you are trying to request a file from your file system and Mozilla's security allows it, but Chrome's does not

Comment: Ya, you need to serve file through a server, a local one for example using WAMP

Comment: Could you put ALL your code up (Datatable, data, etc) so we can see whats going on?   It's true, you're getting a CORS related problem, but it's going to be impossible to help you without knowing exactly what you're doing.  Better yet, create a JSFiddle